# Create pipeline for filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I've enabled the filebeat system module:

```
filebeat modules enable system
filebeat setup --pipelines --modules system
filebeat setup --dashboards
systemctl restart filebeat
```

This is what logstash has to say `pipeline with id [filebeat-7.9.0-system-auth-pipeline] does not exist`

This is the part of logstash that is responsible for it:

```
output {
    if [@metadata][pipeline] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "https://localhost:9200"
            manage_template => false
            cacert => "/etc/elasticsearch/estackcap12extract.crt"
            ssl => true
            ssl_certificate_verification => false
            index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            pipeline => "%{[@metadata][pipeline]}"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "*secret*"
        }
    } else {
    ...
```

Do I need to manually create a pipeline for this? Did I do something wrong? Best I could find is [this doc page page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-pipeline-api.html) but it seem to be for custom things and this is a ready module so I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Comment: What do you get when running this `GET _ingest/pipeline/filebeat-7.9.0-system-auth-pipeline`? 404?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Filebeat connects to Logstash and not ES directly, correct? If that's the case, are you sure that you configured the kibana URL in your filebeat configuration so that it can properly install the ingest pipeline and the dashboard?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I get a 404. Kibana is configured correctly.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the output you get when running `filebeat setup -d "*" --pipelines --modules system`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it returns nothing.

Comment: and what if you just run `filebeat setup -d "*"` ? Can you share your Filebeat config?

Comment: `Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your Filebeat doesn't connect to ES directly but only through Logstash. It's a known issue, but since *Beat can only have as single output, you need to do the following trick.

What you need to do is to uncomment the `elasticsearch` output just when running the setup command, so that Filebeat can install ingest pipelines.

When done, you need to comment out that output again and uncomment the Logstash one before starting Filebeat for real.

If you don't want to modify your configuration file, there's another way by passing configuration variables to `filebeat setup`, like this:

```
filebeat setup --pipelines --modules system \
    -E output.logstash.enabled=false \
    -E output.elasticsearch.username="elastic" \
    -E output.elasticsearch.password="*secret*" \
    -E 'output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities="/etc/elasticsearch/estackcap12extract.crt"' \
    -E output.elasticsearch.hosts="https://localhost:9200"
```